# Is it possible to close the device notification drawer/shade. after interacting with an action button (HTML5 Web Notification API)?

Tags: javascript, notifications, web-notifications

I'm using Javascript to trigger a Notification, that supports "actions"

Either **markAsRead** or **open**

These Notifications render in the device Notifications drawer, as expected, with the relevant buttons.

However when interacting with either button the notification closes, but the drawer remains open.

I found a [long-lived bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=626366) in chromium, that is marked as wont-fix, but its over 7 years old, and I'm hoping someone has a solution.